# Prune simple text log file using C# .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, .net-4.0

An external Windows service I work with maintains a single text-based log file that it continuously appends to. This log file grows unbounded over time. I'd like to prune this log file periodically to maintain, say the most recent 5mb of log entries. How can I efficiently implement the file I/O code in C# .NET 4.0 to prune the file to say 5mb?

Updated:
The way service dependencies are set up, my service always starts before the external service. This means I get exclusive access to the log file to truncate it, if required. Once the external service starts up, I will not access the log file. I can gain exclusive access to the file on desktop startup. The problem is - the log file may a few gigabytes in size and I'm looking for an efficient way to truncate it.

Comment: And are you even sure that you can truncate this log file - perhaps the service has it opened exclusively. Can you perdiodically stop and restart the service to enable you to junk the file? (ServiceController.Stop, etc)

Comment: @Ramhound I was considering using File.ReadLines() (introduced in .NET 4.0) to read the file to an in-memory collection and then write out a new log file with only the last X entries. Was wondering if there's an easier way to truncate the first n lines in a text file.

Comment: @StephenByrne Service restart does not reinitialize the log file. On restart, it continues appending to the existing file. I can however, gain exclusive access to the file by running the truncation routine when I know the external service is stopped. Exclusive access to the log file is not a problem in this scenario.

Comment: @bflat - sorry, I meant to suggest that you could stop the service, truncate your file now you have exclusive access, and restart the service. But I see you are doing this before the service starts up so that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to take the amount of memory that you want to store to process the "new" log file but if you only want 5Mb then it should be fine. If you are talking about Gb+ then you probably have other problems; however, it could still be accomplished using a temp file and some locking.

As noted before, you may experience a race condition but that's not the case if this is the only thread writing to this file. This would replace your current writing to the file.

```
const int MAX_FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 5 * 1024 * 1024; //5Mb;
const string LOG_FILE_PATH = @"ThisFolder\log.txt";
string newLogMessage = "Hey this happened";


#region Use one or the other, I mean you could use both below if you really want to.
//Use this one to save an extra character
if (!newLogMessage.StartsWith(Environment.NewLine))
    newLogMessage = Environment.NewLine + newLogMessage;

//Use this one to imitate a write line
if (!newLogMessage.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
    newLogMessage = newLogMessage + Environment.NewLine; 
#endregion

int newMessageSize = newLogMessage.Length*sizeof (char);
byte[] logMessage = new byte[MAX_FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES];
//Append new log to end of "file"
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(newLogMessage.ToCharArray(), 0, logMessage, MAX_FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES - newMessageSize, logMessage.Length);


FileStream logFile = File.Open(LOG_FILE_PATH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

int sizeOfRetainedLog = (int)Math.Min(MAX_FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES - newMessageSize, logFile.Length);
//Set start position/offset of the file
logFile.Position = logFile.Length - sizeOfRetainedLog;
//Read remaining portion of file to beginning of buffer
logFile.Read(logMessage, logMessage.Length, sizeOfRetainedLog);

//Clear the file
logFile.SetLength(0); 
logFile.Flush();

//Write the file
logFile.Write(logMessage, 0, logMessage.Length);
```

I wrote this really quick, I apologize if I'm off by 1 somewhere.

Comment: "//Use this one to save an extra character" This would save a character from being truncated since every log message would start with a NewLine instead of the ending with one. So the last message would not have an exta NewLine character at the end which isn't needed

Comment: This is good, thanks! Will have to check how this will work for Unicode. Should work for me with a few tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how often it is written to I'd say you might be facing a race condition to modify the file without damaging the log. You could always try writing a service to monitor the file size, and once it reaches a certain point lock the file, dupe and clear the whole thing and close it. Then store the data in another file that the service controls the size of easily. Alternatively you could see if the external service has an option for logging to a database, which would make it pretty simple to roll out the oldest data.

Comment: I will not be running into a race condition for this situation. Please see my update to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a file observer to monitor the file:

```
FileSystemWatcher logWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        logWatcher.Path = @"c:\example.log"
        logWatcher.Changed += logWatcher_Changed;
```

Then when the event is raised you can use a StreamReader to read the file

```
private void logWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
     using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string line;
            string[] row;
            while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
               // Here you delete the lines you want or move it to another file, so that your log keeps small. Then save the file. 
            }
        }
    }
```

It´s an option.

Comment: Btw, in this solution you can use FileInfo class to check the filesize and other properties you might be insterested in

Comment: If you are looking for an easier way to just truncate the file, you may go with FileStream.SetLength Method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength.aspx)

Comment: FileStream.SetLength() looks interesting but will truncate the end of the file. In my case, it is the end of the file (the most recently written entries) that are of interest. Can SetLength() work for this?

Comment: Since exclusive access is not an issue, and i suppose the wanted file size is not too large, maybe you are better off doing a direct memory copy of what you want to keep and writing the new file over the old log. See how this guy does it with memory stream [](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072473/how-to-truncate-a-file-down-to-certain-size-but-keep-the-end-section)