# Can I remove first part of file opened with Filestream?

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, filesize

I'm working with large files using C#. They are binary files. Id like to do some post-processing of these files by removing the 1st 1K of data in the file.

I think there is an obvious way to do this which would be to create a new file and copy the contents of old file into it. However this may be slow given the files could be several GB.
Is there a quicker way using FileStream? I note there is a "SetLength" function and you can also set position in the Stream using "Position" or "Seek". Ive tried experimenting with these but not having any success. eg.

```
using (FileStream fileHandle = new FileStream(theFileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    long len = fileHandle.Length;
    fileHandle.Position = 1024;
    fileHandle.SetLength = len-1024;
}
```

Comment: This answer could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072473/how-to-truncate-a-file-down-to-certain-size-but-keep-the-end-section I am not sure if there is any better way (performance wise)

Comment: The windows methods are more efficient than FileStream in opening and copying files.  Window copy does not open the file.

Comment: You'll have to rewrite the file, see duplicate and [How do I delete bytes from the beginning of a file?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=12153) by Raymond Chen. In theory, if the bytes-to-remove align with the sector size you could modify the MFT record to point to the 3rd sector (so, from byte 1025 of the original file), but that's not trivial.

Comment: @jdweng please elaborate. Are you saying that .NET Streams are slower in copying files than Win32 methods are? And which functions would you use to accomplish this? And what do you mean by "Window copy does not open the file"?

Comment: I'm saying when windows copies a file it does not open the file.  FileStream Open the file which is slower.  To call the windows copy method from c# use File.Copy(source, destination)

Comment: @jdweng But how do you specify the starting point of the source?

Comment: @jdweng I don't even know where to start. In what sense does a file copy not "open" the file? How "slow" is "opening" a file? I sometimes can't shake the thought that you're trolling, or at least that you aren't explaining your thoughts properly. Also, the OP doesn't want to copy the file, they want to prevent that if possible.

Comment: @CodeCaster : Windows copy method duplicates the data in file sectors on the drive.  It is not considered opening a file.  When you use a FileSteam when it opens a file it creates a handle. buffers and points.  Also I answered the question before you edited the question and changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: @jdweng _"Windows copy method duplicates the data in file sectors on the drive"_ - [citation needed]. If you're talking about the `CopyFile` function from Kernel32, it does a whole more than that. It also supports SMB, and what if you're copying to a different drive, with different sector sizes or even a different filesystem? And again, what on earth does that have to do with the OP's question, who wants to **remove bytes from the beginning of a file**? Also, nobody changed the meaning of the question. Nobody ever asked here "what is the fastest way to copy a file", look at the history.

Comment: @jdweng you also may want to read [Inside Vista SP1 File Copy Improvements](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2008/02/04/inside-vista-sp1-file-copy-improvements/) my Mark Russinovich, and try to create a sample program to back up your claims. A call to `FileCopyEx` still involves calls to `CreateFile`, `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` in (very) rapid succession, according to ProcMon.

Comment: @jdweng I have asked a [meta] question: [What can I do about a user consistently spreading misinformation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392514/what-can-i-do-about-a-user-consistently-spreading-misinformation).